# オープンソース版のQtCreatorで例えばBSDライセンスのバイナリが作成できますか？

Tags: qt, ライセンス, qt-creator, gpl

QtCreatorは非Qtのプロジェクトにも対応していると聞きましたが、QtCreatorからLGPLv3ではないバイナリが作成できますでしょうか？

つまり、非QtプロジェクトにQtCreatorがコード片の混入したり、ライブラリをリンクしたりしてLGPLv3のライセンスでリリースしなければならなくなることはないでしょうか？

通常IDEのライセンスがプロジェクトにライセンスが影響するとは思えないのですが、文書で示されたものが見てみたいです。

Android Projectのために GCC/libstdc++ の GPL例外条項は把握しています。これのQtCreator版のようなものを求めています。

Comment: 関連　https://teratail.com/questions/90627

Answer (score 0):

自身見かけたことはなく、[Qtのライセンスに関するページ](https://www.qt.io/qt-licensing-terms/)にもQtCreatorで作成したコード自体のライセンスがLGPLv3になるかならないかは明記されていませんでした。(リンクするオブジェクトの例外項はありました)

個々のソフトウェアのライセンス条件についての確認であれば、ライセンサ当人(Qt Company)に確認するのが確実かと思います。

＃エディタとして使う限りは、自動生成されるコードは0にできます。